# postgresql query not returning expected result

Tags: postgresql

I have formed this postgresql query to return some result:

```
Select 
  TblDailyRch.viewing_date1, 
  TblDailyRch.channel_name1, 
  ((TblDailyRch.Reach/tblUniqViewers4AllChannels.ReachAll) * 100) "Reach %"
From
  (Select 
     viewing_date viewing_date1, 
     channel_name channel_name1, 
     count(distinct party_wid) Reach 
   From 
     tv_viewing_sessions_daily_aggregate 
   Where 
     viewing_date between '20171101' and '20171102' 
   Group By 
     viewing_date1, 
     channel_name 
   Order BY 
     viewing_date1, 
     channel_name1) TblDailyRch,
   (Select 
      viewing_date viewing_date2, 
      count(distinct party_wid) ReachAll 
    From 
      tv_viewing_sessions_daily_aggregate 
    Where 
      viewing_date between '20171101' and '20171102' 
    Group By 
      viewing_date2 Order BY viewing_date2) tblUniqViewers4AllChannels 
Where 
  tblUniqViewers4AllChannels.viewing_date2 = TblDailyRch.viewing_date1;
```

Below is the sample result on running only the first query:

```
 viewing_date |       channel_name       | reach
--------------+--------------------------+--------
 20171101     | 3E                       |  25133
 20171101     | 4FM                      |    253
 20171101     | 4MUSIC                   |   1243
 20171101     | 98FM                     |    236
 20171101     | ALIBI                    |   3468
```

Below is the sample result on running the second query:

```
viewing_date2 | reachall
---------------+----------
 20171101      |   115623
 20171102      |   113898
```

But when I run the complete query, i get below result:

```
 viewing_date |       channel_name       | Reach %
--------------+--------------------------+----------
 20171101     | 3E                       |        0
 20171101     | 4FM                      |        0
 20171101     | 4MUSIC                   |        0
 20171101     | 98FM                     |        0
```

Logically, the query seems correct but I am unable to figure out why on running the complete query, the third columns "Reach %" give result as '0' instead of the expected calculated percent value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of those `COUNT()`s return an integer, and integer division doesn't return decimals. Casting one of them to float will force a float division, returning what you expected.

For example:

```
count(distinct party_wid)::float Reach
```